# MySQL Force Kill Query on Locked Table or Database

Tags: mysql

My environment is Windows 7 and I'm using XAMPP.

I was doing some performance testing on MySQL simulating adding 100 rows at a time. I was doing this using a simple PHP query with for loops.

However, MySQL seems to have locked up as I can't add anything to the table anymore.

I logged into MySQL to look at the process list as below:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 1
   User: root
   Host: localhost:49349
     db: NULL
Command: Sleep
   Time: 2
  State:
   Info: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 17
   User: root
   Host: localhost:49759
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: NULL
   Info: SHOW PROCESSLIST
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried two things:

1. `KILL QUERY 17` to which I got the following result:

   mysql> KILL QUERY 17;
   ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted
2. Then I used the XAMPP controller to stop mysql and then start it again, but that didn't work as the table just seems to be locked permanently.

I also can't add data to the other tables in the database.

Is there a way I can force everything to just reboot/restart i.e. all queries and connections?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I had solved this earlier but forgot to update the question. The table locking up was being caused by the fact that I wasn't calling `COMMIT;` after each query as mysql had autocommit set to false. When this is the case, you have to commit the transaction manually. If you have autocommit set to true, then you don't have anything to worry about.

Comment: What error is it giving you when you try to add data to the table?  What DB engine are you using for the table? The query that you tried to kill in your question was the one that was running the SHOW PROCESSLIST

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database admin and should be on dba.stackexchnage

Comment: @Mark The question is off-topic but the answer is not, a bit of a dilemma here. I'll post the answer shortly

Comment: Strictly your answer does not answer the question, just give the way to do it properly, I suggest editing the question so it asks how to not get into this state rather than how to kill the lock

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I set `PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` to `false` when I opened the `PDO` database connection, and I was trying to run the SQL queries without explicitly committing the transaction.

So I was doing this:

```
$sql_str = "INSERT INTO my_db_table VALUES('data');";
$pdo_stmt_obj = self::$db_handle->prepare($sql_str);
$pdo_stmt_obj->execute();
```

Instead of this:

```
$sql_str = "INSERT INTO my_db_table VALUES('data'); COMMIT;";
$pdo_stmt_obj = self::$db_handle->prepare($sql_str);
$pdo_stmt_obj->execute();
```

Or this:

```
$sql_str = "INSERT INTO my_db_table VALUES('data');";
$db_handle->beginTransaction();                      
$pdo_stmt_obj = self::$db_handle->prepare($sql_str);
$pdo_stmt_obj->execute();
$db_handle->commit();
```

And because I had them in a loop, 100 inserts were being batched (but not committing) each time I run my script (so I wasn't seeing the inserted data when I did a `SELECT`), and I naively mistook that for the database locking up, which it wasn't #InHindsight.